# Spark on Mesos RpcEndpointNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark

I cannot launch a spark job on Mesos, when it starts automatically gives this error:

```
   "Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointNotFoundException: Cannot find
    endpoint: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.32.8.178:59737"
```

Could be because of mismatch between versions? If I launch an example that is brought with the distribution works perfectly.

thanks

Comment: How do you `spark-submit`?

Comment: ./bin/spark-submit --class Main --master mesos://spark-mesos-dispatcher.marathon.mesos:7077 --deploy-mode cluster /home/ggallo/Frequency-assembly-1.0.jar

Comment: You sure it's `mesos://spark-mesos-dispatcher.marathon.mesos:7077`? It should be `mesos://spark-mesos-dispatcher.marathon.mesos:5050`, shouldn't it? But then you'd have faced another error message.

Comment: Yes, sure that is in port 7077. Check the info:http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#cluster-mode.

Comment: In the same page you can find: _"passing in the Mesos master URL (e.g: mesos://host:5050)"_. Please check `5050` instead as I've been using it exclusively and think `7077` is a leftover from Spark on Spark Standalone's docs.

Comment: It is working now, it was application fault that I did not put correctly a data input path. In mesos you have two options to deploy, Cluster Mode or Client Mode. I chose cluster mode and I have a spark daemon (MesosClusterDispatcher) that is always listening to spark job, this is why I use mesos://spark-mesos-dispatcher.marathon.mesos:7077. Thanks anyway for your support

Comment: Can you please answer your own question then for others with a similar case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works now. It was application fault that I did not put correctly a data input path.

In mesos you have two options to deploy, Cluster Mode or Client Mode. I chose cluster mode and I have a spark daemon (MesosClusterDispatcher) that is always listening to spark jobs, this is why I use mesos://spark-mesos-dispatcher.marathon.mesos:7077

Thanks Jacek!